# Powerpoint during an Internal Interview

Tags: interviewing, internal-transfer

I will be applying for an open position within my company, this position is looking mostly for external candidates. Last time I applied and was interviewed for the position, the interview was understandably geared more towards external candidates.

This time around I have an idea of making a Power Point presentation outlining to my boss (and possibly one of the executives if they're in the interview as well), why they should promote me into the position rather than look externally for someone.

I know it's highly unorthodox to do something like that in an interview, and I feel like it would answer a lot of questions they would be asking me anyways, plus would highlight why looking externally isn't as great of an idea as they think. I also feel like it will just be geared towards external candidates again and there won't be a whole lot my boss can ask me anyways.

Would a Power Point be too out there? Or should I just stick to the 'traditional' format of an interview and just answer what questions I can?

Comment: If I was your boss I would probably see this as your trying to second-guess/hijack my hiring process and be quite annoyed by it.

Comment: personally I would get an Oculus and go for a *VR presentation*

Answer (score 4):

Compared to telling them that their ideas are not great, Powerpoint looks at least like it won't be your biggest problem. I can just assume that you intend to phrase this more diplomatically.

But while Powerpoint in an interview is not unheard of it would be unusual to simply start a presentation when your bosses expect they will be conducting a more traditional format. To answer that part of the question I would suggest you announce your intention to have a presentation ready. If they are okay with the idea it might actually be well received (as is shows preperation), if you spring a surprise presentation on them they will quite probably be annoyed and shoot yor down for that reason alone.

Comment: I was planning on asking if I could have the floor for a few minutes and then tell them I brought a Power Point to outline some things.

Answer (score 1):

I'd class this the same as all the other "gimmicks" people do while trying to stand out during the hiring process - and while a *small* minority of interviewers might respond well to it the vast majority won't and it will either fall flat or even worse, actively work against you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I have no idea how a powerpoint presentation can be a good fit at an interview, or how it could be filled with something which cannot be said orally. I hope no interviewer will never ask me to prepare a powerpoint because I could not ever find what to put into it.

Second, and I speak from a former interviewer perspective, I would like candidates to respect any hiring process in place.

Third, as you already are inside the company, you have access to many information and knowledge (on products, processes, people, ...) than any other candidate from outside. Study hard on the job offer and put this into your answers during the interview.

Fourth, are you really sure you are the best fit for the job? When saying

> would highlight why looking externally isn't as great of an idea as they think

you seem to assume that they is no one outside the company who could do the job better than you. This may be seen as pretentious.

Last but not least, avoid [powerpoint every time you can.](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/04/27/world/27powerpoint.html)